# Retrieve related data in many to many relation with junction table using entity framework lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

Here is a simple many to many relation with junction table:
[image: simple many to many relation with junction table]

How could i retrieve related categories of a product using entity framework database first?

I use this sql query for that purpose:

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT Products.*, Categories.Title
FROM Products, Products_Categories, Categories
WHERE (Products.ID = Products_Categories.Product_ID AND Products_Categories.Category_ID = Categories.ID)
```

What's the equivalent **lambda expression** for this?

---

After researching a lot I tried the following code:

**C# in HomeController:**

```
products = oDB.Products.Include(m => m.Products_Categories.Select(a => a.Category))
                       .ToList();
```

After that I should use one of the following ways to access a product's category Title:

```
// i and j are indices
string title = products[i].Products_Categories.Select(x => x.Category).ToList()[j].Title;
string title_0 = products[i].Products_Categories.ToList()[j].Category.Title;
```

The problem with this code is that I cant's access the category when I pass the product object to the view like this:

```
return View(products);
```

I'm looking for some codes like this:

**In .cshtml file:**

```
@model List<olomrayanehDB.Product>
...
@item.Products_Categories.Category.Title // ERROR! this is not working for many to many relations, but I know there's almost the same way coding for one to many relations.
```

---

In summary, how could i pass the products object to the view with it's all related data such as category's title? (I know the solution for one to many relations, here the problem is on for many to many relations **with junction tables**)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your objects don't get populated but:

You dont need to have Product_Categories in there. You can let EF map it directly to a Category list within Products.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany<Category>(s => s.Categories)
            .WithMany(c => c.Products)
            .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("CategoryId");
                        cs.ToTable("Product_Category");
                    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use entity framework database first. So The models are created automatically, and the junction table is in .edmx.